# Keep motion sensor on

Tags: technology, light, automation

Occasionally I need to work at a building with lights controlled by motion sensor. With the recent high energy prices, they have shortened the "lights on" period from 10 minutes to about 3 minutes. It is a real pain to work like that as I need to get out of the place were I am and go to the motion sensor really often or use my phone torch (not ideal and battery draining).

Is there anything that I could attach to the sensor to keep the lights on? I would also need to remove it later.

*It is indoor so air flow is zero... A balloon could work but it is not easy to get it and it won't last 4-6 weeks stored until the next time I need to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Answer Is Blowing In The Wind Lifehack**

Hang a balloon or something like a streamer of ribbon near the motion sensor and use a small fan (battery or AC powered) to keep the object moving long enough to let you finish your work.

Don't forget to leave a note nearby with an explanation and your coordinates for the one who discovers your Lifehack work-around.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

**England Swings Like A Pendulum Do Lifehack**

Pack a small weight with a string attached. It should provide enough motion to keep the lights on for a bit longer than a couple of minutes depending on the length of the string.

An empty container that can be filled on-site might be a bit handier than carrying around an actual weight to swing.

Good Luck!

Comment: The weight should be heavy enough, and the string long enough to have enough momentum to keep swinging for several minutes. When you've done, just stop the swing (or take it down).

Answer (score 2):

How about a [drinking bird toy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinking_bird)?

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinking_bird#/media/File:Sipping_Bird.jpg]

(Image from [Wikimedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinking_bird#/media/File:Sipping_Bird.jpg))